# Spark Structured Streaming resource contention / memory issue

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, spark-structured-streaming

We have a Spark Structured streaming stream which is using mapGroupWithState.  After some time of processing in a stable manner suddenly each mini batch starts taking 40 seconds.  Suspiciously it looks like exactly 40 seconds each time.  Before this the batches were taking less than a second.

[image: Batches taking 40 seconds]

Looking at the details for a particular task most partitions are processed really quickly but a few take exactly 40 seconds:

[image]

The GC was looking ok as the data was being processed quickly but suddenly the full GCs etc stop (at the same time as the 40 second issue):

[image: GC]

I have taken a thread dump from one of the executors as this issue is happening but I cannot see any resource they are blocked on:

[image]

Are we hitting a GC problem and why is it manifesting in this way?  Is there another resource that is blocking and what is it?

Comment: Please take a heapdump and see whether you're hitting SPARK-23682 or not. If you hit the same, Spark 2.4.0 will remedy the issue.

Comment: Hi @Jungtaek - you gave the same answer on the mailing list. And you are right, seems fixed to us in 2.4. We want to test a bit more and I will reply to the mailing list too.

Comment: Ah yes I can’t remember all I answered in mailing list. I hope your issue would be resolved with official Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try give more HEAP space to see if GC was still so overwhelming, if so you are very likely to have mem leak issue

what spark version were you using? If its spark 2.3.1 there were known [FD leakage issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24987) if you were reading data from Kafka (which is extremely common), to figure out if your job is leaking FD, take a look at FD usage in container process in slave, usually it should be very consistently around 100 to 200, and simply upgrade to spark 2.3.2 will fix this issue, I`m so surprised that this issue was so fundamental but never get enough visibilities